# SQL code to generate one occurrence from multiple occurrences of applicationId in queuelog table

Tags: sql, azure

I have a query that results in one `applicationid` being associated with multiple dates. I want to get my query to count all the occurrences of the `applicationid` as one count for the purposes of reporting

The code is currently:

```
SELECT 
    ap.ApplicationId,
    ql.AssignedDate,
    ql.UnassignedDate,
    ql.CompletedDate,
    d.CompletedDate AS FinalDate
FROM
    Application ap
JOIN 
    QueueLog ql ON ap.ApplicationId=ql.ApplicationId
ORDER BY 
    ql.AssignedDate
```

Current results are:

| ApplicationId | AssignedDate | UnassignedDate | CompletedDate | FinalDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2765201 | 2022-02-25 09:55:28.210 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765201 | 2022-02-25 09:55:28.167 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765205 | 2022-02-25 09:55:18.580 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765205 | 2022-02-25 09:55:18.567 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765206 | 2022-02-25 09:55:13.097 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765206 | 2022-02-25 09:55:13.067 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765212 | 2022-02-25 09:54:59.957 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765212 | 2022-02-25 09:54:59.940 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765219 | 2022-02-25 09:54:49.480 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 2765219 | 2022-02-25 09:54:49.467 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

The desired output is to count as *one* every occurrence of the ApplicationId in the Queuelog table that meets the criteria of

```
ql.AssignedDate <= GETDATE()
AND (ql.CompletedDate IS NULL OR ql.UnassignedDate IS NULL) 
AND d.CompletedDate IS NULL
```

EXPECTED RESULT
The occurence which has the most recent date for the appIds that has multiple occurences and those that have one occurence to return that value i.e
|ApplicationId| AssignedDate|   UnassignedDate| CompletedDate|  FinalDate|
|:--------------:|:------------: |:----------------:|:-------------:|---------|
|2765201|   2022-02-25 09:55:28.210|    NULL|   NULL|   NULL|
|2765201|   2022-02-25 09:55:28.167|    NULL|   NULL|   NULL|
to return the first line only

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: @stu have put expected result in the question

Answer (score 0):

**Try out this SQL Query:**

SELECT
ap.ApplicationId,
COUNT(ap.ApplicationId) AS ApplicationCount
FROM
Application ap
JOIN
QueueLog ql ON ap.ApplicationId=ql.ApplicationId where ql.AssignedDate <= GETDATE()
AND (ql.CompletedDate IS NULL OR ql.UnassignedDate IS NULL)
AND ql.CompletedDate IS NULL
GROUP BY ap.ApplicationId

Answer (score 0):

You can use *row_number* to assign a priority to each repeating group and select only the most recent:

```
select 
    ApplicationId,
    AssignedDate,
    UnassignedDate,
    CompletedDate,
    FinalDate
from (
    select 
        ap.ApplicationId,
        ql.AssignedDate,
        ql.UnassignedDate,
        ql.CompletedDate,
        d.CompletedDate as FinalDate,
        Row_Number() over(partition by ApplicationId order by AssignedDate desc) rn
    from Application ap
    join QueueLog ql on ap.ApplicationId=ql.ApplicationId
)t
where rn=1
order by AssignedDate
```